# Exchange 2010 RPC Client Access service won't start

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

Exchange 2010 RPC Client Access service won't start after installing SP3 + Update Rollup 10.

Host is SBS Server 2011.

Have tried multiple fixes on the web but without luck:

- Setting the Microsoft Exchange Information Store service to Automatic(Delayed Start)
- Setting HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\
  MSExchangeRpc\ParametersSystem with a port number
- Re-creating the Microsoft.Exchange.RpcClientAccess.Service.exe.config file.

Event logs:

Event 2280, IIS-W3SVC-WP
The Module DLL C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\ClientAccess\Owa\auth\exppw.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.

Event 5139, WAS
A listener channel for protocol 'http' in worker process '6700' serving application pool 'WsusPool' reported a listener channel failure.  The data field contains the error number.

Comment: Navigate to the Exchange-related event log and provide events ids. Validate there's adequate disk space on the server.

Comment: Added event logs to original post.

Comment: I thought this issue was resolved but unfortunately not.

Comment: Are there any other related entries in the event log? I assume you have validated that the server is assigned adequate amount of resources? The errors above might corresponds to inability of the server to create listener due to lack of resources, additional idea could be to re-create Exchange virtual directories.

Answer (score 1):

The issue i found was that the information store stated first. Stop the IS. Start the RPC client access and see if that starts. Then start IS.